# How to repeatedly fire bullet from a NPC

Tags: python, windows, pygame, sprite

I made an image of a NPC with pygame sprites. The NPC can fire bullets. However whenever I start the game the NPC only fires one bullet to the player. How do I make the NPC fire bullets repeatedly? And is it possible to have a reload delay? Maybe wait a few seconds before firing another bullet. Any help is appreciated. I'm running Python 2.6, Pygame sprites, windows 7.

This is the image of the NPC:

```
class Shooter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(white)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

This is the image of the bullets fired.

```
class ShooterBullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(white)

        self.player = player

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, player, shooter):
        ShooterBulletSpeed = 5
        self.player_x, self.player_y = player.rect.x, player.rect.y

        range = 200
        distance = [self.player_x - shooter.rect.x, self.player_y - shooter.rect.y]
        norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
        direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1 ] / norm]
        bullet_vector = [direction[0] * ShooterBulletSpeed, direction[1] * ShooterBulletSpeed]


        self.rect.x += bullet_vector[0]
        self.rect.y += bullet_vector[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the code below to delay anything for one second like reloading

```
time.sleep(1)
```

I am probably wrong here but i would make a rough guess to say that you could put your NPC's bullet in a `for` loop and play about it like that not much excperince with python games really hope this helps!

Comment: `time.sleep()` will suspend execution, which is _really_ bad practice for most applications. OP should look into using the `pygame.time.Clock`.